# Limit the calendar in jQuery by passing a Php variable

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to limit my calendar to fix dates,  want to set a min value (which is store in a php variable) before that the date can't be selected and also want to set the  max  values as today so that a person can't able to select date after today.

```
              <tr>
                <td class="label"><label for="sales_report_from">From <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                <td class="value"><input type="text" style="width:110px !important;" class=" required-entry input-text" title="From" value="<?php echo $from; ?>" id="sales_report_from" name="from" />
                  <img style="" title="Select Date" id="sales_report_from_trig" class="v-middle" alt="" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);?>skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif"> 
                 <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            Calendar.setup({
                inputField: "sales_report_from",
                minDate:"<?php echo $start_date; ?>",
                 maxDate: 'today',
                ifFormat: "%m/%e/%y",
                showsTime: false,
                button: "sales_report_from_trig",
                align: "Bl",
                singleClick : true
            });
        //]]>

     </script></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="label"><label for="sales_report_to">To <span class="required">*</span></label></td>
                <td class="value"><input type="text" style="width:110px !important;" class=" required-entry input-text" title="To" value="<?php echo $to; ?>" id="sales_report_to" name="to" />
                  <img style="" title="Select Date" id="sales_report_to_trig" class="v-middle" alt="" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);?>skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif"> 
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                    //<![CDATA[
                        Calendar.setup({
                            inputField: "sales_report_to",
                            minDate: '<?php echo $start_date; ?>',
                            maxDate: 'today',
                            ifFormat: "%m/%e/%y",
                            showsTime: false,
                            button: "sales_report_to_trig",
                            align: "Bl",
                            singleClick : true
                        });
                    //]]>
                </script></td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: You mentioned your goal, but no specific problem related to the code  and no question(s). What is the problem and question?

Comment: what library are you using for the calendar ?
Also, mention what is the expected-vs-actual behaviour ...

Comment: everything works fine with calendar but Its not setting the limit